# Bash script to print first the file name and next the size by descending order

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a shell script algorithm that  want to print every file name and its size by order (larger to smaller) of a specific given path. This function is called every time the algorithm finds a file. It  takes as first argument ($1) a file name, as second ($2) the size of file and as third ($3) the number of file.  Every time I call it I want to put the size of the biggest file first in sizeoff array and the files name first in the second array (nameoff). I can't find my mistake.

```
function order_file {
    flag=1
    j=0
    for (( j=0; j< $3 && flag==1 ; j++ ))
    do
        echo $2 $3
        if [ $2 -gt ${sizeoff[$j]} ]; then
            sizeoff[$((j+1))]=${sizeoff[$j]}
            nameoff[$((j+1))]=${nameoff[$j]}
            sizeoff[$j]=$2
            nameoff[$j]=$1
            flag=0
    done
}
```

Comment: can you use `ls -S`? (sort by size)

Comment: @Milag: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

`ls` provides all the information you need, all that is left is extracting the info we need.

If you want to print all the file names and its size in descending order you can use this

```
ls -lSh | awk 'NR>1  { print $NF" "$5}'
```

flag `-h` in `ls` command is for printing size in human readable form. `ls -l` has a one line header in its output, which you don't need, so the `NR>1` condition in awk helps us to skip that line from printing.

`NR` is a special variable in `awk` that holds the current line number that is processed, so here we say execute the code block if the current line number is > 1.

However if you want to only print `count` files

```
count=4 # just an example variable
ls -lSh | awk -v count="$(($count+1))" 'NR>1 && NR<=count { print $NF" "$5}'
```